# "TypeError: Value must be a sequence" when trying to access file with openpyxl.load_workbook

Tags: python, typeerror, openpyxl

I am accessing an excel file on a server in the network with the code

```
import openpyxl
path = r"S:\dic1\dic2\dic3\file.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
```

This is working perfectly fine on my pc but on another pc with exactly the same version of python installed it gives me the following error:

```
raise TypeError("Value must be a sequence")
TypeError: Value must be a sequence
```

How is this even possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The two computers are probably running different versions of openpyxl. You should always include the complete traceback for the exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please Check openpyxl version.

Comment: wow you are right with version 3.0.4 it works but with 3.0.5 it doesn't! thank you so much! do you know what the right path would be for openpyxl 3.0.5?

Comment: Great, it was working on windows but on ubuntu when I changed the version to 3.0.4 it worked, 3.0.5 didn't work on ubuntu