# Openpyxl TypeError: Value must be a sequence when trying to load existing workbook

Tags: python, openpyxl

This used to work but doesn't anymore. Openpyxl version 3.0.5

```
import csv, traceback, openpyxl,re, glob, datetime, calendar, os
from imbox import Imbox

os.chdir('c:\\users\\sariz\\onedrive\\desktop')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('budget sheet.xlsx')
```

```
Output: TypeError: Value must be a
sequence at the 95 (the final line here)
```

This an example of a sheet that is outputted by the program from when it worked:

[image: [sheet demo example]]

Comment: What was the output,?

Comment: I just edited it @Dr.Xavier . Sorry, this is my first ever question here

Comment: Check the version of `openpyxl` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63808495/typeerror-value-must-be-a-sequence-when-trying-to-access-file-with-openpyxl-l)

Comment: I did check the version and included in the question. Its 3.0.5, but im still not sure how to solve the issue @Vaebhav

Comment: @sarizal check this link and follow the steps of the `openpyxl` [Reading openpyxl](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-writing-excel-file-using-openpyxl-module/)

Comment: I still dont understand how to solve this. I used the same command for another program to read an existing excel sheet and it works fine. Ive also read through the link, still cant seem to find a work-around. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63808495/typeerror-value-must-be-a-sequence-when-trying-to-access-file-with-openpyxl-l
This post seems to have the seem problem but not really a solution. @Dr.Xavier

Comment: @sarizal why not? Did you try changing to version 3.0.4?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: Value must be a sequence" when trying to access file with openpyxl.load\_workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63808495/typeerror-value-must-be-a-sequence-when-trying-to-access-file-with-openpyxl-l)

Comment: Also, "*This used to work but doesn't anymore"* - why? What changed? Did you change Python version, openpyxl version? Did it work with a different file? Some information will be helpful

Comment: Please, could you show us demo of your data?

Comment: @Tomerikoo im not sure how to revert back to the old version.. nothing that i know of, i stopped coding for a while (few weeks) and came back and suddenly it didnt work. I have sinced worked with another excel sheet with openpyxl and it worked just fine

Comment: @Dr.Xavier do you mean the excel sheet? i can share it, nothing confidential there, but its just a simple excel sheet with tables showing budget entries and their amounts for months Jan to Sep

Answer (score 2):

YES!! You cracked it! thank you so much @Dr. Xavier for the help and for being so patient! Apparently openpyxl can only read excel sheets that are mainly unformatted, i think it had to do with me using tables. After I created a new blank excel sheet for it to read and enter data it worked just like before. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest with you, I turned to be confused. So, I decided to run the same code you're are running and display to you the `output` and the `traced output`
of your running code;

**Code Syntax**

```
import openpyxl as xl
import os

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\BigDataWork')
wb = xl.load_workbook('x x.xlsx')

sheet = wb.active

cell = sheet.cell(row =1, column= 1)
print(cell)
print('The first value in the Excel file is  ', cell.value)
```

**Code Traced output**

```
Print Output:
<Cell 'PolicyData'.A1>
The first value in the Excel file is  Policy
Variables:
-{
    cell: -{
        py/object: "openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell",
        row: 1,
        column: 1,
        _value: "Policy",
        data_type: "s",
        parent: "<Worksheet \"PolicyData\">",
        _hyperlink: null,
        _comment: null,
        _style: +{2 items}
    },
    sheet: "<Worksheet \"PolicyData\">",
    wb: "<openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook object at 0x0000021B69DBE7F0>"
}
1060 ms
```

**Excel Simple Values** >> *The reason for asking about that is maybe you're an error in your `budget sheet.xlsx`*

[image]

Comment: I've sent an example of a sheet from the excel workbook. Let me know if you need anything more.. Im very confused as to whats wrong as well

Comment: Ahaaa... That's why i asked for sheet demo. Your excel is format so, `openpyxl` can't read the file's data. When it tried to read the sequence of the file and its structure it doesn't work. Try to remove the format of your excel file and make your data clear without any formatting or filter. So, it turns to be clear for `openpyxl` to read. You can check my **Code Traced Output** to understand how the `openpyxl` reads the excel file with fully instructed structure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but updating to version 3.0.7 (or higher) may help. I have an Excel file with pivot tables and formulas and version 3.0.5 could not read it but 3.0.7 can.